# How do I simple calculations in CosmosDB using GremlinAPI

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am using CosmosDB with GremlinAPI and I would like to perform simple calculation even though CosmosDB does not support the math step.

Imagine that I have vertex "Person" with the property Age that can have a edge "Owns" to another vertex "Pet" that also has the property Age.
I would like to know if a given person has a cat that is younger than the person but not more than 10 years younger.

The query (I know this is just a part of it but this is where my problem is)

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").has("Name", "Jonathan Q. Arbuckle").as("owner").values("age").inject(-10).sum().as("minAge").select("owner")
```

Returns an empty result but

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").has("Name", "Jonathan Q. Arbuckle").as("owner").values("age").inject(-10).as("minAge").select("owner")
```

Returns the selected owner.
It seems that if I do a sum() or a count() in the query, then I cannot do 'select("owner")' anymore.

I do not understand this behaviour. What should I do to be able to do a 'select("owner")' and be able to filter the Pets based on their age.

Is there some other way I can write this query?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Steps like `sum`, `count` and `max` are known as reducing barrier steps. They cause what has happened earlier in the traversal to essentially be forgotten. One way to work around this is to use a project step. As I do not have your data I used the air-routes data set and used airport elevation as a substitute for age in your graph.

```
gremlin> g.V(3).
           project("elev","minelev","city").
             by("elev").
             by(values("elev").inject(-10).sum()).
             by("city")

==>[elev:542,minelev:532,city:Austin]
```

I wrote some notes about reducing barrier steps here: http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#rbarriers

UPDATED

If you wanted to find airports with an elevation less than the starting airport by no more than 10 and avoiding the `math` step you can use this formulation.

```
g.V(3).as('a').
  project('min').by(values('elev').inject(-10).sum()).as('p').
  select('a').
  out().
  where(lt('a')).by('elev').
  where(gt('p')).by('elev').by('min')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I would like to filter the persons/airport based on the values from the projection. 
In the air-routes example I would like to see if a given airport is connected to another airport with an elevation lower than the original airport but not more than 10 meters lower.
Can you give me an example of a query like that?